# 'MDCTextInputControllerOutlined' is deprecated in Ios

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, swift5

Using MaterialComponents in Swift 5

Just tried to init a var of MDCTextInputControllerOutlined

```
var controllerVar : MDCTextInputControllerOutlined
```

But getting below message

```
'MDCTextInputControllerOutlined' is deprecated: MDCTextField and its associated classes are deprecated. Please use TextControls instead.
```

Tried to init the var with textField

```
controllerVar = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: inputVar)
```

Getting the below error

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

May I know what is the new way of doing it if old is deprecated

Comment: you can use `MDCOutlinedTextField` and then use properties of it and apply them to your textfield

Answer (score 2):

You can check on their new [documentation](https://material.io/components/text-fields/ios#using-text-fields)

to sum it up

you need this pod

```
pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextAreas'
```

Then import the file or target you want, in this case:

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextAreas
```

In their example you can see this

```
let textField = MDCOutlinedTextField()
textField.label.text = "Phone number"
textField.placeholder = "555-555-5555"
textField.leadingAssistiveLabel.text = "This is helper text"
```

The main difference is that you don't need a controller to apply its properties, you can use the MDCOutlinedTextField directly.
Less code and same result.

Comment: Lord Heisecke back at it again huh